# Cross-platform installator scripts in Python

Tags: python, installation

I have question about writing installator scripts in Python. I have to write scripts in Python, which will work both in Windows and Linux. These scripts have to install some programs **not written in** Python like Git, Java, Tomcat, eclipse, and configure them.

I am not very good in Python (but still learning) and it takes too much time for me to find solutions etc.

I already created required directory structure and copied some files, but I am afraid that my scripts will have many functions with something like:

```
if platform.system()=='Windows':
    exec "Some .bat commands"
else if platform.system()=='Linux':
    exec "Some bash commands"
```

So my question is, are there any useful libraries, tutorials or functions, which could help me?
How for example can I install git from .exe on windows or from tar.gz on linux using python?

It is my marginal task in work, so I would like to not spend much time on it.

Comment: So what's your real question?

Comment: Understand how, your code is right, what's the problem?